# If statement not working in Bash with Strings and substrings

Tags: bash

I have this simple part of my script which compares strings:

```
if [[ "$port" = "Bluetooth PAN" ]]; then
  echo "caught"
elif [[ "$port" = "Thunderbolt "* ]]; then
  echo "caught Other"
else
```

"caught" prints when port is set to "Bluetooth PAN"

when port is set to "Thunderbolt 1" though, "caught Other" is not printed.  Can someone tell me why?  From online searches, * is used to search for substrings.  But what I have is not working and the program continues into the else.

Comment: Log the actual values, as with `bash -x yourscript`. Or, even better, make this a [mcve] by actually including an assignment like `port="Thunderbolt 1"` in the test code -- and make sure the bug still is reproduced when you assign the value yourself!

Comment: `port="Thunderbolt 1"; if [[ "$port" = "Thunderbolt "* ]]; then echo "caught other"; else echo "not caught"; fi` really emits `not caught` for you?

Comment: (Another aspect of a MCVE is making sure the code provided in the question actually runs, which is an element of both "complete" and "verifiable" -- that means making it syntactically valid/complete, so *including* an `else` clause and a trailing `fi`, rather than leaving it to the reader to fill that in for you).

Comment: BTW, if you want to log the value of `port` in such a way as to include it in the question and be sure it's exactly identical to what you're seeing at runtime (with any hidden characters or such represented), `printf 'port=%q\n' "$port"` will do that.

Comment: Have you tried using a regex match?
`elif [[ "$port" =~ Thunderbolt ]]; then`

Comment: @Deathgrip, the equivalent regex to the pattern the OP is using in the question is `[[ "$port" =~ ^"Thunderbolt " ]]` -- anchoring at the top, and forcing the immediate following character to be a space (not a tab or anything else). If they don't want that, they could use `[[ "$port" = *"Thunderbolt"* ]]` and get the same behavior as your regex.

Comment: @Deathgrip, ...which is to say, it's very plausible that using your suggestion will fix their problem, but it'll fix their problem because they don't fully understand the implications of the pattern match they're running (matching only at the start of the line, requiring a literal ASCII space immediately following), rather than because regexes are somehow *better* in some way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Understood and knew I left out the full regex. Rushed to add comment as I was getting ready to head home from the office. Another way to write the full regex without using quotes (but needs an escape) is `elif [[ "$port" =~ ^Thunderbolt\  ]]; then`. But note there are 2 spaces after the backslash.

Comment: Have you tried without the space in the match? If the whitespace in the name isn't a space but a tab?